# $\mathbb{F}_p$ algebra with many $p$th roots of unity

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

An old qual problem reads

> Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ denote the finite field of $p$ elements. Consider
>   the covariant functor $F$ from the category of commutative
>   $\mathbb{F}_p$ algebras with multiplicative identity to abelian groups
>   sending a ring $R$ to the $p$th roots of unity.
>
> - Give an example of a finite local ring $R$ such that $F(R)$ has $p^2$    elements.
> - Let $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$ be the set of natural transformations of    $F$ into itself inducing a group automorphism of $F(A)$ for all 
>     commutative rings $A$ with identity. Prove that $F$ is representable
>     and use the Yoneda Lemma to compute the order of
>     $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$.

For part a, what jumps to mind immediately is the group ring $\mathbb{F}_pP$ for $P$ an abelian $p$ group, which will be local. But the condition on the number of $p$th roots is giving me some trouble. I see that $A$ can't be reduced, otherwise there would be at most $p$ such roots. Any ideas?

Does someone have a suggestion for a reference where I can understand the basics of such algebras better? In particular rings which aren't semisimple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$F$ is representable by the algebra $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^p - 1)$. Since $x^p - 1 = (x - 1)^p$, this algebra is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x - 1)^p$, which is in turn isomorphic to $A = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/x^p$.

Now consider $R = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/x^3$. This is local. Homomorphisms $A \to R$ correspond to elements $r \in R$ such that $r^p = 0$. Elements of $R$ have the form $a + bx + cx^2$, and their $p^{th}$ powers have the form $a + bx^p + cx^{2p} = a$. Hence the elements such that $r^p = 0$ are precisely the elements such that $a = 0$, so there are $p^2$ such elements as desired.

Similarly, the elements $a \in A$ such that $a^p = 0$ are precisely the elements with zero constant term. Each such element corresponds to a morphism $A \to A$ (and vice versa). This morphism is an automorphism iff the linear term of the corresponding element is nonzero (exercise). This gives that $\text{Aut}(A)$ (and hence, by the Yoneda lemma, $\text{Aut}(F)$) has order $(p - 1) p^{p-2}$.

Comment: Thanks! It occurs to me that I need to review (for quals) material along the lines of part (a). Do you have a recommendation for a resource where I could find exposition and exercises along these lines?

Comment: @Eric: not really. I just tried the first example that came to mind.

Comment: In the exercise you gave about showing which maps are invertible, would you suggest just plugging and chugging by composing $x \mapsto y = p(x)$ and $y \mapsto q(y)$ and solving for $q(y) = x$, and seeing when that is possible? (That seems to work.) Or is there a slicker way I'm missing?

Comment: @Eric: that works. There are slicker results you can appeal to about inverses of formal power series under composition but that isn't particularly necessary.

Comment: The question asks us to find natural isomorphisms $F\to F$ which lift to natural transformations of functors into **Grp**. I think if one tracks through Yoneda's lemma, given a polynomial $f\in F\big(\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^p-1)\big)$ the corresponding natural transformation $F\to F$ sends an element $\zeta\in F(R)$ to $f(\zeta)$ for each $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra $R$. I think not all choices of $f$ which give set bijections $F(R)\to F(R)$ for each $R$ will give group automorphisms.